# Distinguish between nsurlrequest from iphone and ipad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, nsurlconnection, user-agent

I have two apps on App-store. one for iPhone and one for iPad with same name.

Now when i am making an API call request to get some data from my servers from these two apps, i collect there user agent on server side.

User agent comes in two form:

1. If API call request made from `NSUrlconnection`
   useragent  :   / xyz....
2. If made from uiwebview: Mozilla('iphone or ipad').

Now for second case , i have no issue in distinguishing between iPhone/iPad.

But for case of  `NSURLConnection` request both have same  and cant rely on

Any other distinguishing parameter can i get from user agent ?

both app are live right now ?

Answer (score 1):

When you create object of `NSMutableURLRequest`  you need to add user agent using the below line.

```
NSString* userAgent = (is_iPad) : "iPad " ? "iPhone";

[request setValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
```

here is_iPad is bool value contain true if app is running in ipad else false.

Comment: Thanks ! yeah i will be adding this to my next update anyhow. my question is until then is there any way to distinguish between iphone and ipad ?
like screen resolutions etc..

Comment: you mean to distinguish iphone or ipad in iOS using screen resolution ?